# Incrementing concatenated fields by ID in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the query below that I need to take the MetaName field and increment the name  grouped by the lst.LISTING_ID and lst.LISTING_SRC_ID fields.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            lst.LISTING_ID,
            lst.LISTING_SRC_ID,
            rt.RLTN_TYP_NM + ' ' + t.PHONE_TYP_NM AS 'MetaName',
            ad.PHONE_NUM,
            lad.PHONE_EXT
FROM   dbo.int_aux_phone ad
   INNER JOIN dbo.int_aux_lst_phone lad
           ON ad.phone_id = lad.phone_id
              AND ad.PHONE_SRC_ID = lad.PHONE_SRC_ID
              AND ad.OWN_LIST_ID = lad.LISTING_ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.int_aux_listing lst
           ON lad.listing_id = lst.listing_id
              AND lad.listing_src_id = lst.listing_src_id
   INNER JOIN dbo.INT_RELATION_TYP rt
           ON rt.RLTN_TYP_ID = lad.RLTN_TYP_ID
   INNER JOIN dbo.INT_PHONE_TYP T
           ON t.PHONE_TYP_ID = ad.PHONE_TYP_ID
```

For Example:

The output from the query above looks like this.

```
 LISTING_ID LISTING_SRC_ID  MetaName               PHONE_NUM            PHONE_EXT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           1000071     Business Phone              (214) 692-5555       NULL
4           1000071         Business Phone              (281) 858-5555  NULL
4           1000071         Business Phone              (210) 344-5555  NULL
4           1000071         Alternate Business Phone    (210) 344-5555  NULL
4           1000071         Alternate Business Phone    (713) 223-5555  NULL
5           1000071         Alternate Business Phone    (713) 223-5555  NULL
5           1000071         Business Phone              (281) 858-5555  NULL
5           1000071         Business Phone              (210) 344-5555  NULL
```

I would like it to look like this

```
LISTING_ID  LISTING_SRC_ID  MetaName               PHONE_NUM            PHONE_EXT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           1000071     Business Phone              (214) 692-5555       NULL
4           1000071         Business Phone1             (281) 858-5555  NULL
4           1000071         Business Phone2             (210) 344-5555  NULL
4           1000071         Alternate Business Phone    (210) 344-5555  NULL
4           1000071         Alternate Business Phone1   (713) 223-5555  NULL
5           1000071         Alternate Business Phone    (713) 223-5555  NULL
5           1000071         Business Phone              (281) 858-5555  NULL
5           1000071         Business Phone1             (210) 344-5555  NULL
```

To clarify the above example if ContactA has three Biz Phones values
Biz phone 
Biz phone
Biz phone

and

ContactB has three Biz Phones values
Biz phone 
Biz phone
Biz phone

when the script runs it needs to output

ContactA

Biz phone 
Biz phone1
Biz phone2

ContactB

Biz phone 
Biz phone1
Biz phone2

Any Help would be great. I talked with a friend and he recommended a while loop Which haven't done before what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    lst.LISTING_ID,
    lst.LISTING_SRC_ID,
    lst.RLTN_TYP_NM + ' ' + t.PHONE_TYPE_NM + replace(' ' + convert(varchar, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by lst.LISTING_ID, rt.RLTN_TYP_NM + ' ' + t.PHONE_TYPE_NM order by rt.RLTN_TYP_NM, t.PHONE_TYPE_NM)-1), '0', '') MetaName,
    ad.PHONE_NUM,
    lad.PHONE_EXT
    FROM   dbo.int_aux_phone ad
       INNER JOIN dbo.int_aux_lst_phone lad
               ON ad.phone_id = lad.phone_id
                  AND ad.PHONE_SRC_ID = lad.PHONE_SRC_ID
                  AND ad.OWN_LIST_ID = lad.LISTING_ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.int_aux_listing lst
               ON lad.listing_id = lst.listing_id
                  AND lad.listing_src_id = lst.listing_src_id
       INNER JOIN dbo.INT_RELATION_TYP rt
               ON rt.RLTN_TYP_ID = lad.RLTN_TYP_ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.INT_PHONE_TYP T
               ON t.PHONE_TYP_ID = ad.PHONE_TYP_ID
```

This query makes the Metanames start incrementing from 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        lst.LISTING_ID,
        lst.LISTING_SRC_ID,
        lst.RLTN_TYP_NM + ' ' + t.PHONE_TYPE_NM + convert(varchar, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by lst.LISTING_ID, rt.RLTN_TYP_NM + ' ' + t.PHONE_TYPE_NM order by rt.RLTN_TYP_NM, t.PHONE_TYPE_NM)) MetaName,
        ad.PHONE_NUM,
        lad.PHONE_EXT
        FROM   dbo.int_aux_phone ad
           INNER JOIN dbo.int_aux_lst_phone lad
                   ON ad.phone_id = lad.phone_id
                      AND ad.PHONE_SRC_ID = lad.PHONE_SRC_ID
                      AND ad.OWN_LIST_ID = lad.LISTING_ID
           INNER JOIN dbo.int_aux_listing lst
                   ON lad.listing_id = lst.listing_id
                      AND lad.listing_src_id = lst.listing_src_id
           INNER JOIN dbo.INT_RELATION_TYP rt
                   ON rt.RLTN_TYP_ID = lad.RLTN_TYP_ID
           INNER JOIN dbo.INT_PHONE_TYP T
                   ON t.PHONE_TYP_ID = ad.PHONE_TYP_ID
```

Comment: Jerrad, Thanks so much this was exactly what I needed worked Like a charm :)

Comment: Jarrod, what would I need to do if I wanted the metanames to start at business phone1 instead of Business phone?